# NSInternalInconsistencyException in UICollectionView while trying to insert a new cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to insert a new cell into _myMusicCollectionView. Datasource is SharedAppDelegate.myMusics array:

```
[_myMusicsCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                                [SharedAppDelegate.myMusics addObject:c.item];
                                [_myMusicsCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:SharedAppDelegate.myMusics.count-1 inSection:0], nil]];
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [_musicStoreCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indPath, nil]];
                            }];
```

I am getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for index path for global index 805306367 when there are only 1 items in the collection view'
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can read in the reason of the error you are accessing a cell at index 805306367. Probably this means `SharedAppDelegate.myMusics.count-1` is negative or `indPath` contains wrong values.

Comment: Yes I see. I want to know where should I insert a new item, and when to perform update?